# How to change VAR name without getting the undeclared error after 'make install'?

Tags: c, autotools, autoconf, automake, cflags

My `configure.in` file has:

```
VAR=yo
AC_SUBST(VAR)
```

`Makefile.am` has:

```
bin_PROGRAMS = hello
hello_SOURCES = hello.c 
hello_CFLAGS =-DVAR=@VAR@
```

C file is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("%s\n",VAR);
    return 0;
}
```

When I do 'make install' there is error

```
Making install in src
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/albertpod/hello/src'
if gcc -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"hello\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"hello\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"1.0\" -DPACKAGE_STRING=\"hello\ 1.0\" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"\" -DPACKAGE_URL=\"\" -DPACKAGE=\"hello\" -DVERSION=\"1.0\" -I. -I.    -DVAR=yo -g -O2 -MT hello-hello.o -MD -MP -MF ".deps/hello-hello.Tpo" -c -o hello-hello.o `test -f 'hello.c' || echo './'`hello.c; \
    then mv -f ".deps/hello-hello.Tpo" ".deps/hello-hello.Po"; else rm -f ".deps/hello-hello.Tpo"; exit 1; fi
hello.c: In function ‘main’:
hello.c:8:13: error: ‘yo’ undeclared (first use in this function)
hello.c:8:13: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
make[1]: *** [hello-hello.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/albertpod/hello/src'
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

So name of VAR becomes yo, but it is undeclared. My goal is to print yo, but how to solve this case?

Comment: can you use something like `hello_CFLAGS =-DVAR='"@VAR@"'` ? By the way your printf is missing quotes: "%s\n".

Comment: As far as I know, `VAR` is for the benefit of the tool chain, not the source code, and `VAR` *is* used in your makefile. But if it *does* substitute symbols in the source code you should try adding `char yo[]= "yes";` above or in `main()` and see what happens. Since the compiler told you it doesn't know anything about `yo` it would be wise to have a `yo` in there somewhere.

Comment: @meuh you were right! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you want the program to deliver the output

```
yo
```

## Proper Quoting in `configure.in`

You also probably noticed that you are missing quotes, to make the replacement text of the define `VAR` a string literal.  The difficulty is that you are passing this value through two instances of the shell that will strip quotes: the one that executes `configure` and the one that is invoked by `make` to run the compiler.  So you need three levels of quoting, with appropriate escaping:

```
VAR="\"\\\"yo\\\"\""
AC_SUBST(VAR)
```

(You can try using single quotes in there to reduce the number of `\`, but it will probably become even more ugly.)

## Proper Quoting in `Makefile.am`

You can also do the quoting in `Makefile.am`.  This is especially useful if you need the value of `VAR` in the Makefile for other purposes too.  You need two levels of qoutes, one to make the value a string literal and one that gets eaten by the shell:

```
hello_CFLAGS =-DVAR='"@VAR@"'
```

This works even if VAR contains (single) spaces or other funny characters, the only problematic characters are `'`, `"`, and `\`.

## Stringification

Alternatively you can let the preprocessor add the quotes using the stringify operator `#`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define STR2(arg) #arg
#define STR(arg) STR2(arg)

int main()
{
    printf("%s\n",STR(VAR));
    return 0;
}
```

The indirection in the macros is necessary due to a quirk how the `#` operator works.  If you would only use one level of macros, the output would be `VAR`.

Of course, this only works as long as the value does not contain any funny characters, like spaces.

## Using `AC_DEFINE`

With `AC_DEFINE` it is slightly easier to define VAR to a value surrounded by quotes.  Use

```
AC_DEFINE([VAR], ["yo"])
```

in `configure.in` and remove `hello_CFLAGS =-DVAR=@VAR@` from `Makefile.am`.  Alternatively, if you need to compute the value of `VAR` in `configure`, use

```
VAR=yo
AC_DEFINE_UNQUOTED([VAR], ["$VAR"])
```

which will interpret shell substitutions in the value.

In both cases, you don't have access to `VAR` in the Makefile.